# Possible to determine the directory to store my own PHP log files into?

Tags: php, linux, windows, logging

Using some *very* simple logging in PHP like the following:

```
function zppLog($text) {
    $logFilePath = 'my-file-path/log.txt';

    error_log($text, 3, $logFilePath);
}
```

I.e. I want to store to *my own* log file.

I'm looking for a way to determine by code where I actually can store the log file into in respect to:

- Have enough write permissions.
- Work both on Linux and Windows.

I thought about reading/parsing the PHP.INI but found no way to do this.

**My question:**

Is there a safe, platform-independent way to get a directory path where my PHP script can write log files into?

*(I am not looking for a logging framework, I'm just looking on how to determine a safe folder location)*

**Update 1:**

To clarify: I want to ship the PHP scripts to various customers with different platforms.

So I have no way in advance to do something manual like asking a hoster about a location that is allowed on a certain server.

This has to be a mechanism that will work automatically.

Comment: *"I'm just looking on how to determine a safe folder location"* - outside the public html area. `$logFilePath = '/var/user/outside_public_html/my-file-path/log.txt';`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Are you sure that the `/var/user` thing will work on a Windows machine?

Comment: yes usually, and hosts will offer a few folders outside the public html realm. You'll need to see what your host has to offer in regards to that, unless you're your own host, then you have complete control over what you can create.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I want to ship the PHP scripts to various customers with different platforms so I have no way in advance to do something manual like asking a hoster. This has to be a mechanism that will work automatically.

Comment: ok. well, TBH, I am not well-versed in that area in order to provide a solution. Wait for more visitors to the question and maybe adding what you said in your question also.

Comment: I think you should not trust the OS.
You can for example write to /tmp/log if the admin left it with default privileges. But then again, service like Selinux can limit you to the defined root directory...